# geopandas can't import

Tags: python, geopandas, python-3, pyproj

I've installed geopandas on ubuntu 17.10 and can't import geopandas. I can't find this particular error anywhere.

```
from pyproj import _proj
ImportError: cannot import name '_proj'
```

I'm using a virtual environment with Python 3.6.3 GDAL 2.2.1
I ran pip install geopandas which also installed dependencies.
Here is output of pip list:

```
bleach (2.1.2)
click (6.7)
click-plugins (1.0.3)
cligj (0.4.0)
cycler (0.10.0)
decorator (4.1.2)
descartes (1.1.0)
entrypoints (0.2.3)
Fiona (1.6.0)
geopandas (0.3.0)
html5lib (1.0.1)
ipykernel (4.7.0)
ipython (6.2.1)
ipython-genutils (0.2.0)
ipywidgets (7.1.0)
jedi (0.11.1)
Jinja2 (2.10)
jsonschema (2.6.0)
jupyter (1.0.0)
jupyter-client (5.2.1)
jupyter-console (5.2.0)
jupyter-core (4.4.0)
MarkupSafe (1.0)
matplotlib (2.1.1)
mistune (0.8.3)
munch (2.2.0)
nbconvert (5.3.1)
nbformat (4.4.0)
notebook (5.2.2)
numpy (1.14.0)
pandas (0.22.0)
pandocfilters (1.4.2)
parso (0.1.1)
pexpect (4.3.1)
pickleshare (0.7.4)
pip (9.0.1)
pkg-resources (0.0.0)
prompt-toolkit (1.0.15)
ptyprocess (0.5.2)
Pygments (2.2.0)
pyparsing (2.2.0)
pyproj (1.9.5.1)
python-dateutil (2.6.1)
pytz (2017.3)
pyzmq (16.0.3)
qtconsole (4.3.1)
setuptools (38.4.0)
Shapely (1.6.3)
simplegeneric (0.8.1)
six (1.11.0)
terminado (0.8.1)
testpath (0.3.1)
tornado (4.5.3)
traitlets (4.3.2)
wcwidth (0.1.7)
webencodings (0.5.1)
widgetsnbextension (3.1.0)
```

Comment: You haven't included any `pip install` output so we can't see if there were any errors...

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem and ended with installing python3 with anaconda, and then installed geopandas with `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas`

conda-forge is community curated packaging for python distribution of anaconda. Since installing geopandas is a hell, they created packages of versions that work with each other. Since then I haven't encountered any problems.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
pip install --force-reinstall pyproj==1.9.5.1
```

Comment: Please dont do posts like this. Your not explaining why it works for you and since your answer wont work for most people (geopandas is *super* dependent on version matching, its the ultimate "dll hell" python package, even fiddlier than psycopg2) this is going to break most peoples installs even worse by subverting the package manager.